# Amplify an application's volume?

Tags: windows-7, audio, spotify

I use Spotify to listen to music on my computer while working. One thing that really bothers me with this software is that it's output volume is very quiet compared to the other software that I use on my computer (Premiere Pro, iTunes, Cubase, Firefox, and pretty much any other software that can output audio). This is not caused by me not having the volume setting at 100 in the windows 7 volume mixer, or anything like that. Spotify just doesn't output as... *loud*... as other applications do.

Normally I'd just tollerate it, but Spotify's output is about %40 lower in volume than the other applications on my computer, meaning that I really have to crank up the volume on my amplifier, which I don't like doing. It causes my audio to distort or crackle sometimes, as well, which I don't like either. I like my music LOUD, and if I want to listen to Spotify loud, I need to turn up my amp 40 percent more than usual, which just isn't good.

Is there some way to raise the volume of this application alone in live time, or some software that would let me do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to automatic-volume-leveling (aka volume-normalization) which adjusts all songs to the same **loudness** volume level; something to try anyway.

I'm not sure
what Spotify's specific policy on this is, but for many music-managers the volume level of the quietest song is used,
all tracks above that are lowered to match its volume level. The reason why the track with the lowest volume is
usually used is that when you digitally increase a track's volume past 100% it results in poorer sound.

[image: screenshot]
[Full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkGPH.png)

In Spotify, go to `edit`, `preferences`, scroll down to the `Playback` section, and uncheck the box beside
`set the same volume level for all tracks`. Now tracks will play at their individual volumes; watch out for
sudden-blaring caused by volume difference between songs (the reason why volume-leveling what invented)!

PS: Make sure you have the volume turned up appropriately within Spotify, it's the bar on the bottom left.